# Trigger to display message using PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I want to create a trigger to display the message “NEW EMPLOYEE DETAILS INSERTED”, whenever a new record is inserted into Employee table, and have this code for it-

```
set serveroutput on;
create or replace trigger display_message 
after insert or update on employee
for each row
when(new.emp_id>0)
begin
dbms_output.put_line('new employee details inserted');
end;
```

But this isn't giving me any output. Please help, thanks in advance!

Comment: `But this isn't giving me any output.` You meant **new employee details inserted** not printed when insert/update employee?

Comment: No, I'm not able to get to the testing level either.

Comment: Hmm...  Looks like there is a problem with your SQL*Plus session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't work only if `EMP_ID` isn't larger than `0`. Is it? In my case, it *works*:

Sample table:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE employee
  2  (
  3     emp_id   NUMBER
  4  );

Table created.
```

Trigger:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER display_message
  2     AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
  3     ON employee
  4     FOR EACH ROW
  5     WHEN (new.emp_id > 0)
  6  BEGIN
  7     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('new employee details inserted');
  8  END;
  9  /

Trigger created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
SQL> INSERT INTO employee (emp_id)
  2       VALUES (100);
new employee details inserted                 --> the message is here!

1 row created.

SQL>
```

Comment: Oh! So all the columns of the employee table should be included in the `when` clause is it?

Comment: Well, that depends on your. In my opinion, you should remove the WHEN clause entirely so that trigger fires "unconditionally". You said that you'd like to see the message "whenever" new row is inserted.

Comment: It didn't work even when I removed the WHEN clause and also when I added all the columns of the table in the WHEN clause using AND keyword. Don't know what else to try

Comment: @yaminir Check if you your session when you run inser  has serveroutput on.

Comment: As you can see (from what I posted), it *works*. If it doesn't for you, then you did something wrong. Please, post your SQL*Plus session - just like I did - so that we'd see what you wrote and how Oracle responded. Don't add that as a comment (as it'll be unreadable) - edit the original message (question).

Comment: Oh god, I din't use `/` after `end;`, so there was no output at all nor error. Yes it worked just fine without the `WHEN` clause as you said. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: That's why it helps if you read carefully :) OK then, you're welcome, I'm glad you made it work.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very poor use of a trigger.  And even worse use of dbms_output.  PL/SQL has zero ability to interact with output devices on the client.  Therefore the output of dbms_output.put_line is not written to your screen. It is written to a buffer, to be processed - or not - by the client.  Some client processes are totally oblivious to the existence of this buffer.  Others, like sqlplus or SQL Developer, know of it, but have to be told to process and display it.  With sqlplus that is via 'set serverout on'.

All that to say, dbms_output is a good debugging tool, but should never be relied upon on in an actual production application.  You need to reconsider why you even want this.  If you execute an INSERT from *any* application it will either succeed or fail.  If it fails, oracle will put an error on the stack that *will* be reported by the client.  If you get no error, then you know it succeeded. Why do you need this message at all?

Comment: "would you please mind having a look" .. Have a look at what?  Unformulated pseudo-code in a comment?  That tells me nothing about what you _really_ do.