# Procedure to insert details by raising exceptions in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to create a procedure to insert employee details into Employee table. Before inserting, check whether the employee age is eligible or not.  Employee age should be 18 or greater.  Values are passed as argument to the procedure. If age valid, insert employee record into table and print the message "Age valid - Record inserted", else print the message "Age invalid - Record not inserted" by raising an exception.
Table: EMPLOYEE

```
Column name   Data type      Constraints

EMP_ID        NUMBER(5)      PK

EMP_NAME      VARCHAR2(25)   NOT NULL

AGE           NUMBER(3)
```

Functional Requirement:

```
PROCEDURE CHECK_AGE_ELIGIBILITY(

 v_id IN EMPLOYEE.EMPID%TYPE, 

 v_name IN EMPLOYEE.EMPNAME%TYPE, 

 v_age IN EMPLOYEE.AGE%TYPE)
```

I have written a code for this as-

```
set serveroutput on;
create or replace procedure check_age_eligibility(
v_id in employee.empid%type,
v_name in employee.empname%type,
v_age in employee.age%type) 
is emp_rec employee%rowtype;
declare
Employee_age number;
BEGIN
SELECT trunc(MONTHS_BETWEEN(TO_DATE(sysdate,'DD-MON-YYYY'), TO_DATE(:new.DATE_OF_BIRTH,'DD-MON-YYYY'))/12)
INTO Employee_age FROM DUAL;
IF (Employee_age >= 18) THEN
update employee;
dbms_output.put_line('Age valid - Record inserted');
else
dbms_output.put_line('Age invalid - Record not inserted');
END IF;
end;
/
```

Please check for any errors since my code editor is not showing any output for this code. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I want to create a procedure, then check for the eligibility criteria and finally print those given statements. Is it all mixed up and wrong? I'm totally confused, please help

Comment: Yeah right, a procedure which does all these actions by itself

Comment: If you are trhying to store 'age' instead of 'date of birth', your data model is fatally flawed.  "Age" changes daily/weekly/monthly/yearly  - depending on how finely you want to slice it.  Store date of birth and calculate age at run-time.  And there is no need to raise an exception.  Just check/calculate age and either insert or don't.  And as I pointed out in your other thread (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64445495/trigger-to-display-message-using-pl-sql) this is not a good use of dbms_output.

Answer (score 0):

You're overcomplicating it. There's no "date of birth" there; you're working with *age* (presumably expressed in years).

So: procedure:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure check_age_eligibility
  2    (par_id       in employee.emp_id%type,
  3     par_emp_name in employee.emp_name%type,
  4     par_age      in employee.age%type
  5    )
  6  is
  7  begin
  8    if par_age >= 18 then
  9       insert into employee (emp_id, emp_name, age)
 10         values
 11         (par_id, par_emp_name, par_age);
 12
 13       dbms_output.put_line('Age valid - record inserted');
 14    else
 15      raise_application_error(-20000, 'Age invalid - record not inserted');
 16    end if;
 17  end;
 18  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> exec check_age_eligibility(1, 'Little', 12);
BEGIN check_age_eligibility(1, 'Little', 12); END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20000: Age invalid - record not inserted
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.CHECK_AGE_ELIGIBILITY", line 15
ORA-06512: at line 1


SQL> exec check_age_eligibility(1, 'Foot'  , 20);
Age valid - record inserted

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * From employee;

    EMP_ID EMP_NAME                    AGE
---------- -------------------- ----------
         1 Foot                         20

SQL>
```

Comment: For this code, my compiler is showing an error stating "check_age_eligibility is invalid"

Comment: It isn't for me, so - feel free to fix those errors. I would, but I don't have any.

Comment: Ah it worked!!! Had to put the procedure name in double quotes like - "CHECK_AGE_ELIGIBILITY". And also the column names don't have the underscore in between as shown in table, but its continuous as shown in functional requirement. Thanks for help again! :)

Comment: You're welcome. Note that Oracle is - by default - case insensitive regarding object names, so - no, you probably shouldn't have used double quotes (unless you used them while creating the object/procedure and used mixed case).

Comment: "Had to put the procedure name in double quotes"  That's because you _created_ them in mixed-case by enclosing them when you create them.  That is probably fine in MSSQL, but in oracle it creates the very difficulty you observe.  _NEVER_ create an oracle object name (procedure, table, column, etc) enclosed in double quotes.  Then you will never have to worry about enclosing them when you reference them.